# Bottom of badge notice is drawing behind profile tabs

Tags: bug, profile-page

I earned a shiny new badge, but the notice box seemed to have some issues.

[image]

It was tested in Firefox 62.0.2 and 62.0.3, as well as Microsoft Edge 42.17134.1.0. A page refresh and forced reload did not fix it.